# Unable to call Core Collapse toggle inside Template repeat Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am trying to toggle the core collapse panel called inside repeating template element. I have provided dynamic ID to the core collapse element but on tap it says : Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function

My code is :

```
<template>
    <template repeat="{{ data }}">
        <style>
            ......
        </style>
        <paper-shadow z="1" class="card">
            <span class="info-bar">{{ cardID }}</span>
            <div vertical layout>
                <div>
                    <div horizontal layout>
                        <div flex style="color:#757575;">
                            <span>Date : </span><br /><span>March 15, 2015</span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align:right;">
                            <paper-icon-button flex icon="subject" style="color:#ed485c;" on-tap="{{ toggle }}" id="{{ cardID }}"></paper-icon-button>
                            <paper-icon-button flex icon="social:share" title="clear" style="color:#ed485c;"></paper-icon-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <core-collapse id="{{ cardID }}">
                    <span> Collapse Content </span>
                </core-collapse>
            </div>
        </paper-shadow>
    </template>
</template>
```

My script is :

```
<script>
    Polymer('i-card', {
        toggle: function (e, detail, sender) {
            var iid = e.target.templateInstance.model.cardID;
            this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#' + iid).toggle();
        },
        ready: function () {
            this.data = this.getData();
        },
        getData: function () {
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                data.push({
                    cardID : 'icard-' + Math.floor(Math.random()*(1000-1+1)+1),
                });
            }
            return data;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I need to toggle their respective collapse element on tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well 1 issue is the click /tap target has the same id as the collapse. that will cause a selecting issue.

what you can do is put the whole repeat template inside a div and give it a id. i will call it "all".

```
 <div id="all">
  <tempalte repeat="{{data}}">
    ....
  </template>
 <div>
```

change the id attribute of your click target to something else it really doesn't matter what it is. i will call the attribute "ident"

```
<paper-icon-button flex icon="subject" style="color:#ed485c;" on-tap="{{ toggle }}" ident="{{ cardID }}"></paper-icon-button>
```

then your function would look like

```
    toggle: function (event, detail, sender) {
        var iid = sender.attributes.ident.value;
        this.$.all.querySelector('#' + iid).toggle();
    }
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed the code as per the answer but now I'm getting different issue.  'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of null'

Comment: I solved the issue. Just made a little change in your code.  In place of getting iid by sender.ident I called `var iid = e.target.templateInstance.model.cardID;` . This work perfect for me. Thanks :)

Comment: glad you got it to work. sender.ident has worked in chrome for me. are you working in chrome? you also could use sender.attributes.ident.value;

Comment: Found another solution. As you were right about setting same id for paper-button and core-collapse was the main cause of error. After removing the id from paper-button my whole code work perfectly fine. I spend my whole week on this little issue.